# Laravel mail renders as escaped HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

Lately, the action buttons in any of my emails don't render as HTML, instead they look like

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="button button-primary" target="_blank">Button Text</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here's what the markdown looks like

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

What's going on?

[Similar question with no answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713894/laravel-mail-html-issue)

Comment: Which exact Laravel version are you using? And is your installation an upgraded one (i.e. project created on 5.4, now on 5.6 or something like that)?

Comment: No, it's a fresh 5.7.17 install. I still haven't been able to fix it, looks like the email mark-up is all sorts of broken.